# I have a problem on Excel when I want to use Application property

Tags: excel, vba, position

I have an Excel application with macros that it is working perfectly with Office 2007 and Windows 7, but when I want to execute the same in Office 10 and Windows 10, fail. For example, a macro for position, `Application.Top = 142`, throw error

> 1004 "method error in _Application object".

This doesn´t happen in Excel 2007.
I appreciate any help
Regards, Carlos

Comment: I can reproduce the error only if the window is initially maximized. Is that the case on your side as well?

Comment: In order to track the origin of the error, can you run the Office 10 code on the Windows 7 computer?

Comment: Actually I run Office 2010 on W10 and Office 2007 on W7, not in other order